# Pytest session fixtures not executed anymore

Tags: pytest

For some time I ran a test suite with the following fixtures in the highest order conftest.py. This file contains fixtures that have to be available for each test in the test suite. They are building on each other. One fixture is requiring the other. Thus the execution order is implicitly clear. The fixtures basically yield objects required for connections.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def A():
    yield A

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def B(A):
    yield B

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def C(B):
```

Then at one moment the setup did not work anymore. Only the first fixture was executed.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def A():
    yield A
```

We are currently trying to check what exactly may have been changed, that changed the behavior. We tried around with a pytest version change, changes in the pytest.ini file or **init**.py files. So far we have not found any reason for the changed behaviour.

Does anyone have a hint?

Comment: How do you invoke the fixtures?

Comment: The fixtures are contained in a conftest.py file. Tests are executed with "pytest testing/", effectively calling for the execution of all tests in various test files and subfolders (and further fixtures in subordinate conftest.py files).

Comment: Yes, but where do you invoke the fixtures? They are not set to `autoUse=True`, so they must be invoked somewhere.

Comment: In a lower order ranking fixture the higher order fixture is picked up
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def justanothersubfixture(B):

Then finally the test is actually invoking the fixtures
def test_finaltest(B, justanothersubfixture):
#final test

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `autouse=True` argument made the fixtures work again.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def A():
    yield A

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def B(A):
    yield B

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def C(B):
```